# How can I see if my serial ports are rs232/485?

Tags: port, serial-port

I need to have a PC with a RS 232 port and a 485 port, currently the PC already has 2 serials but I don't know if they will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from specialist indstrial hardware, all PC serial ports are RS232. This usually doesn't create problems, as there are cheap RS232-RS485 converters available ($2 from China)